# Does the following type of integral have a name?

Tags: integration, terminology

Define $I_{k,b}$ for $k \geq 1$ an integer to be

$$\displaystyle I_k = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\frac{1}{k} - 1}}{(1 + bx + x^2)^{1/k}}dx, $$

where $b^2 - 4 < 0$.

For $k = b = 1$, this is well-known integral whose value is given by $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$. For $k = 2$ this is an elliptic integral. For $k \geq 3$, do such integrals have a name, and are they known to evaluate to some well-known function?

Comment: this integrals can be related to disgusting objects called appell functions

Comment: for $b=0$ u get something nice namely beta functions